# python invalid syntax while reading line content of a file

Tags: python-2.7, file

I want to read a file line by line, but I have an error while reading it

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

The file `file.txt` contains only one line which is `test example`.

I got this error while executing the code above :

```
File "file.txt", line 1
  test example
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just want to read the line content as a string, not as a variable or a command or anything else.

Comment: Please open your command line and check your python version, it is possible you are not actually on python 2.7 where the 'with' keyword was first reserved

Comment: I am in python 2.7.12+

Comment: Are you very sure you don't have `import test` (or something like it) at the top of your program? The error message indicates that the Python interpreter thinks there should be Python in the file. That doesn't happen if you `open` it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh my god I am stupid. The error came from a bad execute command. I was specifying arguments without the python file to execute ...

Comment: Thanks. I did this same mistake :).

Comment: Same here! Facepalm...

Comment: facepalm. me too

Comment: lol did the same

Comment: My wife did the same thing and bugging me that the code doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should probably be more along the lines of this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line
```

You have to make sure to actually read the lines as well. If you have any more issues, check out this great guide on reading and writing python text files:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Normally, using `f` is preferable to `f.readlines()`. It makes little difference in this context, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too, in Python 3:

f = 'file.txt'

with open(f) as f_obj:

```
for line in f_obj.readlines():

    print(line)
```

Answer (score -2):

In python 3.x the code is implemented as below

```
fr=open('file.txt','r')
for line in fr:
   print line
```

So my suggestion is that to create a file object and use it in for loop

Comment: The question is tagged as python 2.7

Comment: Also, why are you avoiding the context manager? And using pre-3.x print syntax?